# calculating magnitude of a number in java

Tags: java, math

I forgot the function in Java to calculate the magnitude of an integer. help please..

|5| = +5 = 5

|-5| = +5 = 5

so if  a - b   is  - x

mag (a - b) is x a posstive number..

Comment: Are you looking for Math.abs()?

Comment: You mean the abs() function, aka absolute value?

Comment: damn, what's the appropriate close reason to use for "couldn't be bothered to check the API docs" ?

Comment: @Alnitak I kept looking in to arithmetic operators of java.. but couldn't find any... did my search before putting question here..

Comment: @Alnitak For some people, because of their mathematical experience the regular term for "absolute value" is "magnitude", or sometimes you might be able to remember the term "magnitude" but not "absolute value". So, whilst some version of Math.abs() is present in just about every programming language, and "absolute value" might be easily found in the API docs, the term "magnitude" is not quite so. Therefore it's a valid question, it caused no pain or damage for anyone to answer it, and now this Q appears at the top of a Google search for 'java magnitude function'. Therefore net positive.

Comment: @BenjaminR I think I must have learnt how to program (BASIC c. 1980) and used the `ABS` function before I learnt the mathematical concept of "magnitude" ;-)

Comment: @BenjaminR: The fact that the OP put vertical bars around quantities in their question (|5|) leads me strongly suspect they're familiar with the concept of "absolute value"—so probably aren't as naive as you give them credit for being.

Comment: +1: I was always taught the term was _magnitude_. That's what I searched for. Forgot computer guys like to say _absolute value_.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [Math.abs()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#abs%28double%29). Using this function:

```
5 = Math.abs(5) = Math.abs(-5)
```

Comment: +1 because you provided a code example to match the question.
(and because you weren't snide to the Asker...)

Answer (score 3):

Try [Math.abs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#abs%28double%29).

```
abs(-4) = 4;
abs(5) = 5;
```

Answer (score 2):

The function's [in the Math library](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) and is called `abs()` (short for "absolute value").

Answer (score 2):

Math.abs() is the function you are looking for.